# Bind List of Employee to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I want to show Employee List data in the Data Grid. When I run below code empty grid is displayed.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWpfApplication1.DataGridBindToEmployeeList"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataGridBindToEmployeeList" Height="300" Width="300" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWpfApplication1.ViewModel">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:EmployeeInfo x:Key="employeeInfo"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource employeeInfo}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="300" Width="300" >
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeId}" Header="Employee Id" Width="300"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeName}" Header="Employee Name" Width="300"/>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

DataContext:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeInfo
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }

        public EmployeeInfo()
        {
            EmployeeList = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeId = i, EmployeeName = i.ToString() + "ABC" });
            }
        }
    }
```

Output Should Be:

```
Employee Id   | Employee Name
1             | 1ABC
2             | 2ABC
3             | 3ABC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource employeeInfo}, Path=EmployeeList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="300" Width="300" >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeId}" Header="Employee Id" Width="300"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeName}" Header="Employee Name" Width="300"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

at the moment you set `ItemsSource` to whole `EmloyeeInfo` class and you want to point to your `ObservableCollection<Employee>`, also you forgot to wrap your column in `DataGrid.Columns`

Comment: Code throws exception after adding path "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."

Comment: updated my answer but basically you forgot to wrap column in `DataGrid.Columns`

Comment: Thanks for reply. From some other code of my project is throwing same error. Can you please tell me why this error comes up "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."

Comment: @user2323308, in you original code you forgot to specify that you're now declaring columns by using `DataGrid.Columns` and by default, if not other tag is specified `DataGrid` assumes that you want to create items hence the error that you cannot have items comming from 2 sources as you had `ItemsSource` defined and then tried to add 2 column definitions as `Items` manually. Most likely in this other place you also forgot to enclose part of XAML in `Control.SomeProperty` and it's assuming that you're adding items